# Azure Functions Dependency Tracking for SQL Server and Service Bus Into Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, .net-6.0

Previously I have Azure Web App (.net core) and It successfully track the SQL Server and Service Bus dependency into Application Insights. It is not working some how with Azure Functions.

Environment

- dotnet 6
- dotnet-isolated mode
- log level default set to "Information".
- Azure Environment using Consumption plan for Azure Functions.
- Application Insights key is configured.

I have Azure API management at front and backend is Azure Function and that call SQL Server and Service Bus.

- Api Management Service to Azure function dependency successfully resolved but Azure Function to other component is not working.

Comment: Have you configure app insights for your function app (startup) ? When running in `dotnet-isolated` mode, the function app host wont collect dependencies related to your code.

Comment: @Thomas Function app startup ( More specifically program.cs) is as it is like for dotnet-isolated mode. I have registered dependency with DI but nothing related to application insights. Any suggestion ? what could be the configuration  ?

Comment: Just `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();` from this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for information but it was not working with isolated mode. I have tried in proc function and it works fine. Also there is one more package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService and it seems to be working with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know I am posting my own answer. Also there are chance that in future there may be some good solution or it get integrated the way it is in in-process mode.

By then follow steps.

1. Add Package

```
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService
```

2. In program.cs in configuring host.

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
```

More info at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service

Comment: I want to add that this also works for all types of dependency calls, not only SQL. I was facing the same issue when trying to have HTTP calls tracked. Great job finding a solution @dotnetstep

Answer (score 2):

The only way I've managed to solve this issue so far was by setting up custom Middleware

```
.ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(config =>
{
    config.UseMiddleware<AiContextMiddleware>();
})
```

In the IServiceCollection you need to setup simply

```
.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService()

public class AiContextMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
    private readonly TelemetryClient _client;
    private readonly string _hostname;

    public AiContextMiddleware(TelemetryClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
        _hostname = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AI_CLOUD_ROLE_NAME");
    }

    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var operationId = ExtractOperationId(context.TraceContext.TraceParent);
        
        // Let's create and start RequestTelemetry.
        var requestTelemetry = new RequestTelemetry
        {
            Name = context.FunctionDefinition.Name,
            Id = context.InvocationId,
            Properties =
            {
                { "ai.cloud.role", _hostname},
                { "AzureFunctions_FunctionName", context.FunctionDefinition.Name },
                { "AzureFunctions_InvocationId", context.InvocationId },
                { "AzureFunctions_OperationId", operationId }
            },
            Context =
            {
                Operation =
                {
                    Id = operationId,
                    ParentId = context.InvocationId,
                    Name = context.FunctionDefinition.Name
                },
                GlobalProperties =
                {
                    { "ai.cloud.role", _hostname},
                    { "AzureFunctions_FunctionName", context.FunctionDefinition.Name },
                    { "AzureFunctions_InvocationId", context.InvocationId },
                    { "AzureFunctions_OperationId", operationId }
                }
            }
        };

        var operation = _client.StartOperation(requestTelemetry);

        try
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            requestTelemetry.Success = false;
            _client.TrackException(e);

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            _client.StopOperation(operation);
        }
    }

    private static string ExtractOperationId(string traceParent)
        => string.IsNullOrEmpty(traceParent) ? string.Empty : traceParent.Split("-")[1];
}
```

It's definitely not a perfect solution as you then get two starting logs, but as end result, you get all logs traces + dependencies correlated to an operation.

I've solved this issue in the first place like that, now I'm revisiting whether there are any better ways to solve this.

Let me know too whether you managed to solve this issue on your side.